# Combining history of merged branches in GIT?

Tags: git, merge, branch

In my git repository, I have merged branch "B" into "master", getting the the following structure:

```
--> A --> B --> C --> D  (branch master)
    |           |  
    F --> G --> H        (branch B)
```

I now want to combine the branches to get the following history:

```
--> A --> B --> F --> G --> H --> D
```

How can I do this?

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume `C` is a merge commit, and that's the reason you don't want to have it in your result.

What you need, to do what you want, is [git rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Let's start of with yet another schematic commit graph. To leave the original
branches intact we will operate on a new branch called `rebasing`

```
git checkout -b rebasing master

--> A --> B------------------- --> C --> D         (branch master) (branch rebasing)
     \                           /
      +----+->  F --> G --> H -+                   (branch topic)
```

Just rebase everything between `topic` and `rebasing` onto `topic`.

```
git rebase --onto topic topic rebasing
```

or do the same with a shorter command

```
git rebase topic

-> A -> B -----------------> C -> D                (branch master)
    \                      /
     +---+>  F -> G -> H +                         (branch topic)
                          \
                           +---------> B -> D      (branch rebasing)
```

Now when we just look at `rebasing` we have a straight line form `A` to `D`.

```
-> A -> F -> G -> H -> B -> D                      (branch rebasing)
```

So, the only problem right now might be that the order is different from what
you expected. You could easily fix that by reordering commits with `git rebase
--interactive`, if you want to.

Or you rebase everything in a slightly more complicated way. Let's start again.

```
--> A --> B------------------- --> C --> D         (branch master) (branch rebasing)
     \                           /
      +----+->  F --> G --> H -+                   (branch topic)
```

First take everything from `C` to the tip of `master` (aka. `D`) and put it on the
tip of `topic` (aka. `H`) :

```
git rebase --onto topic C master

-> A -> B ----------------> C -> D                (branch master)
    \                      /
     +----> F -> G -> H +                         (branch topic)
                          \
                           +---------> D           (branch rebasing)
```

One last rebase, at the end, and we are finished.

```
git rebase B

     +----> F -> G -> H +                         (branch topic)
    /                     \
-> A -> B ----------------> C -> D                (branch master)
         \
          +------------------------> F -> G -> H -> D   (branch rebasing)
```

Voila!

```
-> A -> B -> F -> G -> H -> D                      (branch rebasing)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would branch from A and then cherry pick in the commits that you want

so:

```
git checkout -b my-branch A
git cherry-pick B
git cherry-pick F
git cherry-pick G
git cherry-pick H
git cherry-pick D
```