# Combine an old merged branch into a single history

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have a `master` branch, with a now deleted `merged` branch "redesign".

```
A - B - C - D - E    (master)
    |       |
    F - G - H        (redesign)
```

Is it possible to combine the `merged` "redesign" branch into `master` so I have a single uniform history?

```
A - B - C - F - G - H    (master)
```

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are you saying you want to eliminate the merge itself?  It sounds like you're describing a rebase operation, but bear in mind that if you've already published, this will involve a history rewrite.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Oliver, Yes I want to eliminate the merge itself. i am the only dev, so a history rewrite is fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining history of merged branches in GIT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474959/combining-history-of-merged-branches-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `git rebase --interactive` will do the trick. On your master branch do

```
git rebase --interactive <commit hash of B>
```

and pick every commit. If you want to reorder the commits just swap the lines.

---

**EDIT:**

Just found a similar question with a community wiki answer: [Combining history of merged branches in GIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474959/combining-history-of-merged-branches-in-git)

Comment: I had success with your answer, and not with the other answer. My question is different to the other listed as my branch has been deleted.